# Will the measure space be sigma-finite?

Tags: measure-theory

Assume that you have a sigma-finite measure space $(\Omega ,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a measurable function.
It can be shown that

$\mu^*(A) = \int_A f d\mu, A \in \mathcal{A},$

is a measure. **I am wondering if it will be a sigma-finite measure?**

I am not sure how to construct the sets $C_n$ with $\cup_nC_n=\Omega$, and $\mu^*(C_n)<\infty.$ One idea is to set $C_n=\{\omega: f(\omega)\le n\}$, but if you look at the function $1/|x|$ on the real line with the Lebesgue measure we see that this is not enough.

Is there a counterexample to this?

Comment: Maybe consider $$D_{n,m}=\{x\in C_n:|f(x)|\leqslant m\}$$ where $C_n$ are the measurable sets with finite measure covering $\Omega$

Comment: @Alessandro Thank you very much, that works!